# Assembler can someone explain part of code

Tags: assembly, x86, tasm

maybe someone can explain what does this code:

```
   MOV SI,80h     
    XOR DI,DI      
    MOV BL,[SI]    
    INC SI         

    MOV AH,9
    LEA DX,info     
    INT 21h

    OR BL,BL        
    JZ be_arg       

    INC SI
    JMP su_arg      

be_arg:     
    MOV AH,9
    LEA DX,input1
    INT 21h

...
su_arg:
    XOR DI,DI
vej:
    MOV AL,[SI]
    CMP SI,100h
    JZ vej_j

    CMP SI,100h
    JZ vej_j

    MOV [failas+DI],AL

    INC SI
    INC DI
    JMP short vej

vej_j:
    JMP input_juz
```

there

```
    failas DB 80h DUP(0)
```

As I understand there can be read some arguments which can be written when you run the program so then it goes to "su_arg", or I'm wrong? 
If I'm right, what it can be for example?

Would be nice if someone could explaine this code with details.

P.S. Using Assembler Tasm

Comment: Why not use a debugger (DOS's `dbg.exe`) to step through the code?  Here is the [`int21`](http://stanislavs.org/helppc/int_21.html) reference if you don't already have it.

Comment: Throw away assembly code without comments.  It isn't worth your time.  Nor ours.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Who cares what DOS does, these days? Well, you have to know, to understand this code. If you started your program as "myprog foo", the "foo" is a "command line argument". DOS puts this in the latter part of the PSP (Program Segment Prefix). At address [80h] is the total (byte) count of the command line argument(s). The first part of your code puts this value in `bl`. Then you print something - we don't know what, 'cause you didn't show us! The `or bl, bl` doesn't alter the value in `bl`, it just sets the flags. If the value was zero, you jump to a section that presumably prints "no command line arguments were given", or such. As shown, it then drops through to `su_arg:` - perhaps the `...` indicates some code that does something more sensible. At this point, you copy the entire remainder of the PSP to a buffer at `failas`. We had the "count" in `bl`. We also know that there will be a carriage-return (13 decimal or 0Dh) at the end of the command line arguments. You might want to overwrite the CR with a '$'. to be able to display it with int 21h/9. But nooo, you copy the entire remainder of the PSP. Maybe that's okay for whatever you're planning to do with it. Fairly horrible code - C+ at best. If your instructor gave you this, fire him! :)